# Best way to create multiple classes in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

My program has a single class that holds cost information for estimates. I now need to create 6 different options(each option holding the same data as the estimates class) that could be attached to each of these estimates. The only way I can think of to do this properly would be to create 6 different classes called option1, option2, ... This is fine accept it seems kind of sloppy. Is there some way to setup a single class that can hold all 6 options that map to a single item on my original table of estimates?

Written in: ASP.NET MVC 4 using Entity Framework

I hope this is clear, please let me know if i need to elaborate on anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer. Visit the [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) site for more info on this. It's really hard to give you the full course in an answer here. It's basic class structure.

```
public class Estimate {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Option> Options { get; set; }

   public Estimate() {
      Options = new List<Option>();
   }
}

public class Option {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public Estimate Estimate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had tried to do what you suggested a similar way before but I basically did not know how to code it properly for code first so that the relationships between the two tables was setup correctly. Now I have an issue with deleting parent/child objects and will open a separate thread on that.